# Multiple target names with same result?

Tags: makefile

Hey all. I was wondering, if I want to have two targets do the same thing in my makefile without duplicating, how would I go about this?

For example:

```
Cat:
    $(CC) -o a.out

Feline:
    $(CC) -o a.out
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Cat Feline:
        $(CC) -o a.out
```

You can list multiple targets as well as multiple dependencies.

Comment: @mathepic: True, although I assumed it was an example for the sake of an example and not something that was supposed to make sense.

Comment: I wonder what @mathepic originally observed!? :)